# What exactly does import as do?

Tags: python, python-import

I've tried to find cases of what does `import module as x` do, but can't seem to find any explanations of what it does and how it works. I found it being used while searching up how to use tkinker. Can anyone explain what it does and how do I use it?

Comment: We're glad you're here and we want to help you and this is a very broad question that isn't really related to solving a programming problem. W3 have faith that you can Google this one.

Answer (score 1):

```
import example_module as x
```

imports the module "example_module" and allows you to refer to it as "x" in your code. This can be helpful for modules with long names. 
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0221/